# SQLite запрос SELECT

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Помогите понять, почему программа выдает ошибку при логической обработке запроса SQL SELECT.
Смысл в том, что нужно проверить существует ли в БД код клиента, если нет просто вывести сообщение.
Если код есть, все работает корректно. А вот если запрос не находит код, программа сообщения не выдает.

```
db_path = 'Bonus_db.sqlite'

    def go_to_Check_Client(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        cur = conn.cursor()

        code = self.codefield.text()
        cur.execute('SELECT SoldTo FROM Customers WHERE SoldTo = ?', (code,))

        if len(code) == 0:
            self.error.setText('Please fill in Customer Sold-to')
        elif cur.fetchone() is not None:
            if int(code) == cur.fetchone()[0]:
                self.error.setText('Customer with this Sold-to already exists')
            else:
                self.error.setText('Customer can be saved')
        else:
            self.error.setText('Customer can be saved')
```

Comment: Если `code` не является пустой строкой, то условие `if len(code) == 0` никогда не выполнится

Comment: @andreymal в том то и дело, если значение переменной 'code' пустое, то программа выполняется. Не выполняется последнее, когда введенное в code значение не находится. В данном случает у меня "уехали" отступы
Почему то не получается в комментарий вставить код нормально


'''
        if len(code) == 0:
            self.error.setText('Please fill in Customer Sold-to')
        elif int(code) == cur.fetchone()[0]:
            self.error.setText('Customer with this Sold-to already exists')
        else:
            self.error.setText('Customer can be saved')

Comment: Не надо вставлять код в комментарии, исправьте отступы в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Если запись в БД не найдена, то проверка `elif int(code) == cur.fetchone()[0]:` не сработает, а если точнее, то в этом месте будет брошено исключение, так как идет доступ к элементу списка по индексу 0, тогда как в списке нет ни одного элемента. Так как бросается исключение, то программа не доходит до ветки `else`.

Правильно проверять будет так: `elif cur.fetchone() is not None`. Проверять конкретное значение нет смысла, так как вы ищете по коду и его же возвращаете, значение не может отличаться от того, что вы передали в условие. Важно только наличие или отсутствие возвращенной записи.

Comment: Переписала код и опять тоже самое :(  если введенный код =0 или если код в БД существует, все работает. А если код в БД не найден выдает ошибку почему то на другую строку, хотя вложенные условия должен пропускать.. отступы все 20 раз перепроверила :( не понимаю, почему он идет дальше..
    if int(code) == cur.fetchone()[0]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Что вас не понятно из моего объяснения? Я же объяснил, что в таком виде код работать не будет и написал, как его изменить. В у вас все та же проверка и, ожидаемо, все та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Если вкратце то:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT SoldTo FROM Customers WHERE SoldTo = ?', (code,))
code, = cur.fetchone() or (None,)
# остальное на Ваше усмотрение
```